# How to handle number format exception and replace int/double variable with default value of 0/0.0?

Tags: java

```
              try {

                 price = Double.parseDouble(tokens[3]);
                 count = Integer.parseInt(tokens[4]);

             }catch (NumberFormatException n){

                 price = 0.0;
                 count = 0;
             }
```

In the code above I have what my try-catch block currently looks like, and I am trying to figure out how to replace the values with 0 if the input is **a string or negative value**. I am not sure if I can do this in one try-catch or if I need two separate ones. I am kinda new to java so any help would be appreciated !!!

Comment: your code seems to be working fine where is the problem ?

Comment: If first line throws an exception, second line will not work. Even though token[4] is not a string or negative, count will be 0. For this reason,  using two try-catch block is more sensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, if the price was parsed correctly and the count is not, both price and count will be set to 0. I think this is not what you need to do.

If you need to handle each one separately, i.e. if price was parsed correctly but count is not, then you will have to put two different try-catch blocks for each of the two vars.

Also, this code doesn't check for negative. If number is negative, it will not throw a NumberFormatException. You will have to check this after successfully parsing the numbers.

```
  try {

             price = Double.parseDouble(tokens[3]);
             if (price <0)
                 throw new NumberFormatException();

         }catch (NumberFormatException n){

             price = 0.0;
         }




   try {

             count = Integer.parseInt(tokens[4]);
             if(count <0) 
                 throw new NumberFormatException();

         }catch (NumberFormatException n){

             count = 0;
         }
```